# A const data member prevents automatic generation of both copy and move ctors?

Tags: c++11, constants, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

Consider the following class:

```
struct A 
{ 
    int const x;
    A(int x) : x(x) { }  
}
```

Will this class get automatically generated move and copy ctors? Or is this prevented by the presence of the `const` field member `x`?

From my experience the answer is that move and copy ctors will not be generated, but I haven't found an explicit mention of this in the standard. Is there anything in the standard that implies that in this case the move and copy ctors are not generated?

Of course, the same questions apply to move/copy assignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy and move constructors will be declared as defaulted and not defined as deleted (that is, they will be generated). They will have the expected behavior (recall that the "move constructor" of a nonclass type has no effect on the source object).

The copy and move assignment operators will be declared as defaulted but will be defined as deleted, per **[class.copy]**/23:

> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class `X` is defined as deleted if `X` has [...]
>
> - a non-static data member of `const` non-class type (or array thereof) [...]

Comment: What does the move constructor do? It *copies* (i.e., uses the copy ctor) the `const` data member from the moved from object?

Comment: @becko for a non-class object there's no difference between copying and moving, so yes.

Comment: `int` was just an example type for the data member. But if it had been a complicated class, my question is valid. If the data member is `const`, the automatic move ctor can only copy the data member, right?

Comment: The move constructor will not be called on a `const` object, because the signature for a move constructor is `T(T&& other)`, not `T(const T&& other)`.

Comment: @rlbond almost - if a constructor `T(const T&& other)` is provided then it's formally a move constructor; it would have to be a very strange class though.

Comment: That's correct, but I decided not to include it in my comment because it's a strange language quirk that is essentially irrelevant.